# How do I resolve the error Invalid file name: It must contain only [^a-zA-Z0-9_.]+

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, cross-platform

I'm implementing google OAUTH for a Xamarin application I have downloaded the google-services.json and placed it in  Solutionname.Android in visual studio solution, when I click on the file google-services.json in properties under Build Action i do not see the option GoogleServicesJson, I believe I need to Rebuild the solution for this option to be available, when I rebuild in Visual Studio, I get the error below

[image]

Error       Invalid file name: It must contain only [^a-zA-Z0-9_.]+.    Solution.Android    C:\Users\username\source\repos\SolutionFolder\Solution.Android\google-services.json

Comment: “-“ are not allowed in Android file names

Answer (score 0):

In renaming google-services.json to google_services.json solved the above error but introduced another error invalid file path 'C:\Users\username\source\repos\SolutionFolder\Solution.Android\obj\Debug\110\res\google_services.json'

Comment: renaming it to googleservices.json resolved the new error